# Why redirect_to in around_filter or after_filter won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, filter

How to make redirect_to works in those filters?

I'm trying to change

```
def start 
  ....
  redirect_to index
end

def end
  ...
  redirect_to index
end
```

to

```
around_filter :around

def around
  ...
  yield
  redirect_to index
end 

def start
  ..
end

def stop
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the action is complete it renders the template automatically, thus you cannot render / redirect after the request is complete. You could solve this by putting the `redirect_to` at the end of the actions that you need it for. This is not what `around_filters` were designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your actions already have a `redirect_to` or `render` call. You cannot call these methods twice per request.

Answer (score -1):

You can change `response.location`, which has the same effect as calling `redirect_to`.  An example with an `after_filter` (the same could be done with around):

```
  after_filter :different_redirect, only:[:create]
  def different_redirect
    if self.status == 302
      response.location = other_thing_path
    end
  end

  def create
    @my_thing = MyThing.new(params[:my_thing])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_thing.save
        format.html { redirect_to(my_things_path) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```