# how can I DRY up my controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have the following controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

  def a
    foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    foo.a

    redirect_to foo_url(foo)
  end

  def b
    foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    foo.b

    redirect_to foo_url(foo)
  end

  def c
    foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    foo.c

    redirect_to foo_url(foo)
  end

end
```

Is there anyway to get a after_filter to perform the shared redirect code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181687/why-redirect-to-in-around-filter-or-after-filter-wont-work

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to map the Foo public methods to FooController actions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

  [:a, :b, :c].each do |name|
    define_method(name) do
      foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
      foo.send(:name)
      redirect_to foo_url(foo)    
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Even though you answer is correct, I find it highly unlikely to be used in a real world controller. Assuming the example in the question is just a generic schematic, `define_method` won't be much of use.

Comment: This solution will work well if the user is trying to execute a method on the payload based on controller action. This type of patterns are quite common when you are performing contextual actions on the payload object (like, dislike, mark, bookmark, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

An `after_filter` will not work in this situation.

I would use the following approach.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_foo, :only => [:a, :b, :c]

  def show
  end

  def a
    do_and_redirect(:a)
  end

  def b
    do_and_redirect(:b)
  end

  def c
    do_and_redirect(:c)
  end

  private

  def get_foo
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def do_and_redirect(method_name)
    @foo.send(method_name)
    redirect_to foo_url(@foo)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code refactored:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_foo, :except => [:show]

  def show
  end

  def a
    @foo.a
    redirect_to @foo
  end

  def b
    @foo.b
    redirect_to @foo
  end

  def c
    @foo.c
    redirect_to @foo
  end

  private

  def get_foo
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: I would omit the last method (redirect_to_foo) and keep it simply `redirect_to @foo` in the actions

Comment: Yeah, I am actually using decent_exposure so the @foo = Foo.find part is not an issue.  I just was trying to get all those methods to automatically redirect without having to have that duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000319 says you can use the after_filter.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it where it is. after_filters won't work in this case.