# How to redirect users to a custom web page each time `params` contain a `redirect_uri` value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am running Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to implement a feature that redirects users to a custom web page when they perform an action by providing a `redirect_uri` parameter. In other words, I would like to "trigger" the redirection each time the `redirect_uri` value is present in `params` and the redirection should happen in any case (e.g., when GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP requests are executed with HTML or JS formats) after the process flow has been fully accomplished (e.g., when the HTTP verb is POST then the redirection should happen after submission).

*Bonus* - If possible, I would like to validate the URL (e.g., link correctness) in cases when the referrer URL comes from outside the application domain.

How should I make that the proper way?

Comment: Adding `redirect_to params[:redirect_uri] if params[:redirect_uri].present?` in `before_action` filter should do it, I think.

Comment: @kiddorails - I updated the question since the redirection should happen after the process flow has been fully accomplished. For example, when the HTTP verb is POST then the redirection should happen after submission.

Comment: By 'after process flow', do you mean, that POST action should finish it's execution? In that case `after_action` filter?

Comment: @kiddorails - Yes, 'after process flow' means that the redirection should happen after the POST action finish execution. I thought of using `after_action`/`around_action` filter but I do not how in my case?

Comment: Err. You have the `params[:redirect_uri]`, you have the `actions` and you have the _hook_ (`after_action`). Make sure you `permit` this parameter in controlle.

Comment: @kiddorails - OK, I have all those tools of which I am aware. But how to use those in order to solve the issue? This is the question. For example, Rails'd raise errors if there are multiple responses in the same controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181687/why-redirect-to-in-around-filter-or-after-filter-wont-work), once your action encounters `redirect_to/render` statements, the request flow will be complete and `after_action` redirect may not be trigerred.

How about creating a controller action like `custom_redirect_to` as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def custom_redirect_to(url)
    redirect_to (params[:redirect_uri].present? ? params[:redirect_uri] : url)
  end
end
```

and then use this method in your controller actions instead of `redirect_to` as:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params)
  if @post.save
    custom_redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Since I am not sure on what to do I open a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764473/drawbacks-and-support-for-adopting-a-custom-redirect-to-method

Comment: @Backo Replied in that thread with some generic way to achieve that. Let me know if that serves the problem :)