# Drawbacks and support for adopting a custom `redirect_to` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In order to [redirect users to a custom web page each time `params` contain a `redirect_uri` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763607/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-custom-web-page-each-time-params-contain-a-redirec) I am evaluating to use a [custom `redirect_to` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763607/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-custom-web-page-each-time-params-contain-a-redirec/27764290#27764290) this way (by [@kiddorails](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376448/kiddorails)):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def custom_redirect_to(url)
    redirect_to (params[:redirect_uri].present? ? params[:redirect_uri] : url)
  end
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params)
  if @post.save
    custom_redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

However I would like to be aware of possible drawbacks and to receive support for adopting the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing a redirect target to be set through a URL parameter without any validation is potentially dangerous for your users, because it makes fishing attempts easier.

An attacker can send links to your users such as

http://my-trusted-site.com/some/action/path?redirect_uri=malicious-site-that-looks-like-trusted-site.com

, and many users will only see the domain part and fail to realize where they end up after clicking that link.

The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) therefor [considers this a vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet):

> Unvalidated redirects and forwards are possible when a web application
>   accepts untrusted input that could cause the web application to
>   redirect the request to a URL contained within untrusted input. By
>   modifying untrusted URL input to a malicious site, an attacker may
>   successfully launch a phishing scam and steal user credentials.
>   Because the server name in the modified link is identical to the
>   original site, phishing attempts may have a more trustworthy
>   appearance. Unvalidated redirect and forward attacks can also be used
>   to maliciously craft a URL that would pass the application’s access
>   control check and then forward the attacker to privileged functions
>   that they would normally not be able to access.

It's important that you check the redirect_uri parameter carefully before executing the redirect.

But since proper validation is tricky and prone to errors, an even better idea is not to accept URI parameters in the first place, but to allow certain keywords instead that specify where the user will be redirected.

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    protected

  def dynamic_redirect_to(default_route, options)
    options.stringify_keys!

    redirect_to options.fetch(params[:redirect_to], default_route)
  end
end
```

You can now define any number of allowed keywords in advance which may be used as the `?redirect_to=` parameter:

```ruby
def create
  @post = Post.new(params)
  if @post.save
    dynamic_redirect_to post_path(@post), edit: edit_post_path(@post)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

If `?redirect_to=edit` is set, the user is redirected back to the edit page. If the parameter is not set or contains an unspecified keyword, she is redirected to the default `post_path(@post)` instead.

Comment: How should I validate URL? What kind of checks should I perform on URLs?

Comment: That depends on what you want to allow your users to do. Can you describe what your users are doing, and why you want to redirect them?

Comment: Example scenarios: 1) After updating a Post an user can be redirected to the edit action (instead of the Post show action), depending whether he had selected a form check field. 2) A user is on Page A and clicks a link to change the current application language, so having access to the language form. After updating the language the user should be redirected to the Page A (instead of the Language show action).

Comment: @Backo in that case, you do not have to accept arbitrary URIs. You can offer pre-defined keywords instead, which are much safer. I have updated my answer with example code.

Comment: And if I validate that the `redirect_uri` contains just the `path` (that is, that it does not contain the `host`) so that the redirection'd happen "inside" the `myapp.com` domain name? Would it be more sure?

Comment: @Backo how would you check that the redirect is a path? By checking that it starts with a '/', right? So you just add `redirect_to params[:redirect_to] if params[:redirect_to][0] == '/'`, and all is well. Wrong: now someone comes along and enters `?redirect_to=//evilsite.com`. That's called a [protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), it's perfectly legal, and it's just one tiny example. Just don't do it. There's a good chance you miss something, and your users will get owned later down the road.

Comment: I would check like this: `URI(redirect_uri).host.nil? ? redirect_uri : nil`. Is it enough?

Comment: @Backo if you want to do it, do it. My recommendation not to do it stands.

Comment: BTW - (1) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10 (2) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet#Redirects_and_Forwards

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what janfoeh said above. 
But to implement your requirement, I hacked around in [Rails code of redirection](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L69) to make it simpler.

Make a file **config/initializers/redirecting.rb** with:

```
require 'abstract_controller/base'
module ActionController
  module Redirecting
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include AbstractController::Logger
    include ActionController::RackDelegation
    include ActionController::UrlFor

    def _compute_redirect_to_location(options)
      if redirect_url = session.delete(:redirect_uri)
        options = redirect_url
      end
      case options
        # The scheme name consist of a letter followed by any combination of
        # letters, digits, and the plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-")
        # characters; and is terminated by a colon (":").
        # See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.1
        # The protocol relative scheme starts with a double slash "//".
      when /\A([a-z][a-z\d\-+\.]*:|\/\/).*/i
        options
      when String
        request.protocol + request.host_with_port + options
      when :back
        request.headers["Referer"] or raise RedirectBackError
      when Proc
        _compute_redirect_to_location request, options.call
      else
        url_for(options)
      end.delete("\0\r\n")
    end
  end
end
```

In your **app/controllers/application_controller.rb** :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  before_action :set_redirect_uri
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def set_redirect_uri
    session[:redirect_uri] = params[:redirect_uri] if params[:redirect_uri].present?
  end
end
```

And Voila! Now you can continue to use the original `redirect_to`, and whenever `redirect_uri` is supplied in the url, it will set that url in session and automatically override.  :)

**Note**: I am clearing `session[:redirect_uri]` only when `redirect_to` is called. You can easily modify that behavior to reset this session depending upon the requirement.